# Biometric keepass

Tags: security, password-manager

I use KeePass to store my passwords, but it still concerns me a little bit that now *all* my passwords are guarded behind a single password. It would be nice if it could do 2-of-3 authentication (not sure if there's a name for this). e.g. you must provide 2 of the following 3 options: a password, face recognition, TOTP.

This way if I forget my pass or lose my phone or my face gets burnt in a fire, I can still access my password database, but it's also more secure than a password alone.

Is there any software that does this?

**OS:** Windows 10, Linux (Ubuntu), *and* Android. (it's OK if certain versions only support 2 of the 3 methods -- it just means they'll be non-optional)

**Budget:** I guess I'd pay up to 10 or $20 if this worked well. Depends how good the software is. Free + open source is of course always preferred :-)

---

Must have features:

- Must store usernames, passwords, URLs and Notes
- Must be easily searchable
- Organize entries into folders
- X-of-Y authentication (discussed above)

Nice to haves:

- Ability to assign each entry an icon
- Auto-type (select entry and press button to re-focus last window and autotype username + password in secure fashion)
- Global auto-type (hotkey that will work when any app has focus)
- Nestable folders
- Ability to import KeePass KDBX file

---

Aside: How would facial-recogition-as-a-key even work? Passwords work because they have an exact byte sequence that can be used to encrypt another piece of information, but a mugshot does not have that property.

Comment: Perhaps [Intel Truekey](https://www.truekey.com/)?

Comment: So the solution must not necessarily work with KeePass, but could be a different password manager, right? If that’s the case, please list the basic features the password manager would need to have.

Comment: You could setup key-based authentication in addition to a password, effectively putting a two-factor authentication scheme. Not quite the same as face recognition but adds more security than just a password.

Comment: @Alejandro I noticed that. The idea is you'd put the keyfile on a USB stick right? Then unless you have the stick, you can't get in? But what if your USB key breaks? Or if I don't have it with me? There's too many concerns with that I think.

Comment: @unor I've updated the question as per your request. It doesn't have to be a KeePass [2] plugin, but it sure would be nice (save me the trouble of porting ~300 passwords)